# Adding multiple external domains in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension, which uses multiple APIs. Currently I have it set up so that I can use one of these APIs, but trying to add a second to the manifest won't work. I tried a couple of things resulting in either the extension not workin or the manifest file being invalid.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://domain-1.com; object-src 'self'",
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://domain-2.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Gives invalid manifest error

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://domain-1.com; https://domain-2.com; object-src 'self'",
```

Only works for the first domain

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://domain-1.com, https://domain-2.com; object-src 'self'",
```

Gives invalid manifest error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can be only one `content_security_policy` entry. You can specify multiple domains but you have to separate them by spaces and not by commas:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://domain-1.com https://domain-2.com; object-src 'self'",
```

For more information see [CSP specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/), in particular the [examples section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#examples).